# No natural scrolling or two-finger right click option in gui and dconf editing not working - Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity desktop

Tags: unity, touchpad, scrolling, dconf, huawei

as the title indicates I cannot enable natural (australian/reverse) scrolling. I have checked the usual location, (system settings -> mouse and touchpad) but this is a minimal menu with no mention of scrolling. I then edited the dconf database with the dconf editor GUI, I set all natural-scrolling booleans to true, but this also did not work. Finally I tried using xinput but I can't even see the touchpad name in xinput (virtual core input or something, but not a real hardware device). I am using a Huawei matebook D 14. I would also like to enable two-finger right click as this option is also nowhere in settings. The mouse and touchpad settings seem so incredibly minimal that I am wondering if I am missing configuration files or something, surely there are more than 2 settings related to the mouse or touchpad in ubuntu. I have attached screenshots of my mouse and touchpad settings and d-conf gui window.

Thanks in advance for any advice, and if there is no easy solution please let me know as I will simply go back to normal gnome desktop.

Thanks for reading[image][image]

EDIT: The output of xinput as suggested below[image]

EDIT 2: Output of xinput list-props 11:

```
Device 'ELAN2204:00 04F3:3109 Touchpad':
Device Enabled (149):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (151): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (302): 0
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (303): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (304):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (305):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (306):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (307):   0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (308):  1, 0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (309):  1, 0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (310):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (311):    1
libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (312): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (313):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (314):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (315):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (316):    0
libinput Accel Speed (293): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (294): 0.000000
libinput Left Handed Enabled (298): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (299): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (271): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):    0, 0
Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event8"
Device Product ID (275):    1267, 12553
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (300):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (301):   1
```

EDIT 3:

Thanks to Pilot6's helpful advice, I have discovered that a command that enables natural scrolling:

```
xinput set-prop "ELAN2204:00 04F3:3109 Touchpad" 286 1
```

the 286 refers to the number of the property for natural scrolling. My only question now is how to make sure this runs on start-up. I will investigate and post my answer if I find one.

Comment: This obviously is related to inability of unity to control libinput. Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Please now add output of `xinput list-props 11`. Please post it as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: There is an easy solution.

Comment: It is easy to set on startup. I will give you a link.

Comment: There is an easier command `xinput set-prop 11 286 1` ;-)

Comment: that is better, thank you for all your help, everything is working now. I actually added the command to start-up applications which seems to work fine.

Comment: There is no need to add to startup.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to use two-finger tap for right click with unity desktop?

Comment: I didn't try it, but I used libinput with unity and it worked. Len me see... Hold on.

Comment: Does 3-finger work? 2-finger used to work on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You can also try to use synaptics instead of libinput, but there may be other problems.

Comment: No 3-finger does not work. 2-finger works perfectly under GNOME desktop, but not Unity. It is interesting that it worked in 16.04, was there a xinput device property that has been removed? I will read about synaptics, thank you for the continued assistance :)

Comment: The libinput property is set correctly `Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (308):  1, 0`. That must be some unity issue.

Comment: `sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: That worked! unfortunately it temporarily disabled my keyboard and I had to do

    sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all

but now everything is working, keyboard and also 2-finger right click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable Natural Scrolling in `libinput` add

```
Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
```

to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`.

It should be added before `EndSection` to the touchpad section.

Unity desktop GUI app can't use `libinput` options.

You can switch to synaptics by

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```